# How can I turn off the hint function, which is highlighted when I write the code using Android Studio?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, ide

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0RfN.png)

The problem above happens when I write the contents or parameters inside the method.
Trying to solve the problem above,

I approached to File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance

There are lots of setting related to some kind of code helper.

I checked on and off every setting at the Appearance, but nothing changed.

Could you help me solve this problem??

Answer (score 3):

Another wrong or outdated answer.
The right answer is disabling Inlay Hints in Settings / Editor / Inlay Hints / Parameters Name.
Click the link to see the image, not enough rep to post images.

[Android Studio Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU3oJ.png)

Comment: Please put the pertinent information in your answer in addition to the link. Link only answers can get deleted by the bot.

Answer (score 0):

To disable hints completely, uncheck
*Settings → Editor → General → Appearance → Show parameter name hints*.

[image]

Another method might be to right-click on the hint, then on
"Disable Parameter Name Hints".

The keyboard shortcut for this might be <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866202/intellij-shows-method-parameter-hints-on-usage-how-to-disable-it)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, you untick a "Show the parameter info.." box in Settings → Editor → General → Code Completion...

[image]